# Youtube javascript api pagination params

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

In the youtube api v2 documentation. It recommended to use `rel="previous"` and `rel="next"`
 to work with pagination.

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?start-index=51&max-results=25
```

Let say the above link, start with 51 and limit 25 videos params within the link.
My problem is, I don't want to use the link directly, I want to separate the params and pass to my function params.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question, this is fairly easy to do, just break the string up into chunks and insert your function parameters.

```
function make_url(start_index, max_results) {
    return "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?start-index=" + start_index + "&max-results=" + max_results
}
```

Then calling make_url(100, 25) will return a url like this.

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?start-index=100&max-results=25
```

Comment: but youtube api json doesn't provide separate start_index and max_results.  They come with the link together.